# Challenge : Curved text extraction using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr

I have some text images but they are curved like, in circle or wave form. I need to make them straight. I tried to extract text using OCR but they are inefficient, they need straight image.
I am attaching Test Images: 
[image: Test Image in wave form]

[image: Test image in circle form]

I need to cover these two minimum area.
Please suggest some path or using code for text extraction. 
Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The characters are aligned on circular arcs.

After reconstructing the chains from the nearest neighbor relations, use the centroids of the characters, and take them in triples (or more). You can estimate the sign of the curvature and split between the concave/convex sequences. Then you can estimate the arc centers/radii and unwrap the text.